# "Rest Assured" requests log: Duplicate requests prints

Tags: rest-assured

I am working with InteliJ although I don't know if that is important...

When I debug a my code which uses "Rest Assured", every request is being printed **twice** to the Intelij Run\Debug window.

For example:

```
@testR
Feature: tests Feature
Run Before Feature
**Request method:   POST**
Request URI:    https://10.188.10.30:443/auth/api/login
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    username=admin
                password=admin
**Request method:   POST**
Request URI:    https://10.188.10.30:443/auth/api/login
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    username=admin
                password=admin
10:34:44: Step: Given Login to tenant "system" with username "admin" and password "admin"(Scenario: New Login)
```

I defined my requestSpecification as:

```
    requestSpecification =
            RestAssured
                    .with()
                    .baseUri(baseUri)
                    .port(port)
                    .filter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
                    .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
                    .log().all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either only one

```
 .filter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
                .log().all();
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me - but ResponseLoggingFilter and not RequestLoggingFilter... Why?